# Mysql stored procedure and Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Making first steps with Mysql stored procs.  I have the following declaration but when I run it I get the error:  `Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function`  but I am not using a `GROUP BY` or aggregate anywhere, am I?

```
delimiter //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS myDB.FiscalYearCleanup//
CREATE PROCEDURE myDB.FiscalYearCleanup 
    (IN year INT)
BEGIN 
    --
    -- Fiscal Years "end" in the named year
    -- So, FY2000 starts on July 1, 1999 and ends on June 30, 2000
    --
    -- Only use years that exist in the current pool of events
    --
    DECLARE testYear INT DEFAULT 0;
    SELECT 
        year
    FROM
        myDB.eventLog
    WHERE
        year BETWEEN YEAR(MIN(date)) AND YEAR(MAX(date)) 
    INTO testYear;

    IF testYear = year THEN
        SELECT CONCAT('Year is in range: ', year) AS message;
    ELSE 
        SELECT CONCAT('Year is out of range: ', year) AS message;
    END IF;
END//
```

Answer (score 1):

You are indeed using aggregates: the `MIN` and `MAX` in `year BETWEEN YEAR(MIN(date)) AND YEAR(MAX(date))`.

The fix to your stored procedure turns out to be quite simple: change the `WHERE` in your query to `HAVING`.

Conditions in a `WHERE` clause are applied before aggregation takes place.  Conditions in a `HAVING` clause are applied after aggregation.